# how can I deal with Problem on Graph in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph

Question:

Consider the Initial value problem $$x'(t) = t*x^2$$ and $x(0)=1$

Solve this problem using ode45 for $ 0 \le t \le 1 $ and plot the result. And try solving again for $ 0 \le t \le 2 $

---

> My matlab code for t in [0, 1] is as follows:

```js
function f = fun( t, x )


f = t*x.^2;

end

>> [tv1 f1] = ode45 ('fun', [0 1], 1);
>> plot(tv1, f1)
```

And I get the following graph

[image]

However, when I run this Matlab code for t in [0, 2]

```js
function f = fun( t, x )


f = t*x.^2;

end

>> [tv2 f2] = ode45 ('fun', [0 2], 1);
>> plot(tv2, f2)
```

I get the following graph,

[image]

Why this last graph for t in [0, 2] is wrong? How can I correct it?

Many thanks for your helps!

Comment: The graph is not wrong. Your quadratic differential equation `f=t*x^2` results in a third degree polynomial after integration. Do `ylim[0 100]` to better follow what is happening in your graph.

Comment: where do I insert this ylim[0 100]. Please can you write at this point in clear and exact way? @RealReza

Comment: Right after `plot(tv2, f2)`. Also, change the upper limit to smaller and larger values (i.e. instead of 100 use 10 or 500 or etc) to understand the graph

Comment: Okay thank you for help. Also can you say a feedback about the solution of the problem. Is this matlab solution codes correct for the given question ? Is there any mistake? For example, first graph looks correct? etc..? dear @RealReza